# do I need to learn sqldeveloper-specific commands for PL/SQL queries?

Tags: plsql

There are statements like

```
SET server output ON
PRINT var_name
DEFINE var_name
VARIABLE  var_name
```

etc. which are typed outside the PL/SQL block. These are SQL+ commands which also seem to work on SQlDeveloper, both of which are tools to execute PL/SQL scripts in. Is there any standard that these non-PL/SQL commands follow, i.e. since they are tool-specific, they can differ, say in, SqlDeveloper and SqlPlus. Whose statements should I learn ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should learn the commands supported by the tool you are using - SQL Plus commands for SQL Plus, etc.  There is overlap between SQL Plus and SQL Developer because SQL Developer has been designed to be easy to use by people who have previously used SQL Plus.  To see which SQL Plus commands SQL Developer supports, open its online help and navigate to:

- SQL Developer Concepts and Usage

  - Using the SQL Worksheet

    - SQL*Plus Statements Supported and Not Supported in SQL Worksheet

Comment: Thanks. But have these non-PL/SQL commands been standardized ? Can they work across different DBMSs like MySql, etc.